# How to add NOT NULL constraint where the column data type is NON INTEGER (say VARCHAR(50))

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to an existing table. Succeeded for the first column (`EMPID`), but failed to add the constraint for the second column (`EMPNAME`).

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_primarykeyPOST2
(  
     EMPID INT,
     EMPNAME VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO tbl_primarykeyPOST2
    SELECT '1', 'GURMIT SINGH'   UNION ALL
    SELECT '2', 'KISHORE KUMAR'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '3', 'SHAHID ANWAR'   UNION ALL
    SELECT '4', 'ANDREW'         UNION ALL
    SELECT '5', 'ISMAIL'

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_primarykeyPOST2

ALTER TABLE tbl_primarykeyPOST2
    ALTER COLUMN EMPNAME VARCHAR NOT NULL
```

Comment: You need to specify the length of 50 again

Comment: Also: if you have an `Int` column, you **should not** put literal values you're inserting into single quotes - you're basically defining a **string** which SQL Server then has to convert back to an `INT`. Just use the number as is - no quotes or anything! `SELECT 5, 'ISMAIL` .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying the type `VARCHAR()` in SQL Server, you always need to specify the length.  This is a good idea, even where there is a default length (the default actually varies by context).  So, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_primarykeyPOST2 
    ALTER COLUMN EMPNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ;
```